# QObject::moveToThread and executing a member function inside that thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4

If an object of type `QObject` is moved to a thread with `QObject::moveToThread`, all signals that the object receives are handled inside that thread. However, if a slot is called directly (`object->theSlot()`) that call will still block. What would be the normal way of executing that call inside the thread and returning control to the calling thread immediately? Hacks with `QTimer` don't count. Setting up a single purpose connection and deleting it again might count as a solution if all else fails.

Comment: Do you want to do it using `QObject::moveToThread` then? If not I would rather put all computations in a object which will not receive signals, and use my method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with Qt::ConnectionType set to Qt::QueuedConnection

Comment: This sounds incredibly close to what I'm looking for. Wouldn't this behave the same as `AutoConnection` given that the object is already in another thread?

Comment: You're right. AutoConnection will do the same, BUT! I always preffer to put this argument into code, to see what was my intention to use QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run ( Function function, ... )` to launch some execution inside a separate thread and then use `QFutureWatcher` to get the result. You will not need to call `movetoThread`.

Basically something like :

```
QFutureWatcher<T>* watch = new QFuture(0);
connect(watch, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleResult()));
QFuture<T> future = QtConcurrent::run( myObj, &QMyObject::theSlot(), args...);
watch.setFuture(future);
....

//slot
private void handleResult(){
  if(future->isCancelled())
     return;  
  T mydata = watch->future()->result();
  // use your data as you want
}
```

`QtConcurrent::run` will schedule the method of this object to be ran in some thread. It is non-blocking. On the other hand, `QFuture::result()` blocks until there is a result, if the computation is still ongoing. That's why you need the other object to notify when the computation is over using `finished()`. I cannot think of a better design for your problem in Qt.

Comment: This executes `theSlot` in the context of the `QtConcurrent` thread, not in the context of the thread of `MyObject`.

Comment: Yes but does it matter?? Why am I downvoted? After all he just want to execute `theSlot()` in a different thread than the caller thread.This even perform better than creating a thread and calling start: [Qthread vs QRunnable](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/videos/watch/enhancing_your_qt_application_with_multiple_threads)  .Or did I misunderstood `pmr`?.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Your alternative makes the `moveToThread` away, which makes all other slots non-concurrent. It has it's drawbacks, but it would still make sense under certain circumstances. I'll go for Ton's hack though.